# Referencing an object more than once in a line

Tags: java, object, space-efficiency

So I'm writing my version of Tetris. Here's what I'd like to do:

`screen[0][1].setColor(Color.RED);
screen[0][1].setStatus(1);`

Is there a way to do this in only one line?

Comment: You could make a method combing the two into one for all future calls.

Comment: rewrite the `setColor` and/or `setStatus` methods to return `this`. Then it's `screen[0][1].setColor(Color.RED).setStatus(1)`. The real question is: why would you need to? I severely doubt you're running into performance issues over these two lines, keep them nice and readable =)

Comment: Whoa @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that's pretty clever. I guess it really doesn't accomplish anything though.

Answer (score 3):

A few options spring to mind:

- Write a method in whatever class this is which knows about both the status *and* the color:

  ```
  // Implicitly sets color to red. Consider using an enum for statuses
  screen[0][1].setStatus(1);
  ```
- Write a method accepting both state and color parameters:

  ```
  screen[0][1].setColorAndStatus(Color.RED, 1);
  ```
- Make `setColor` and `setStatus` (and other setters) return `this` so you can chain them:

  ```
  screen[0][1].setColor(Color.RED).setStatus(1);
  ```
- Abandon the "all in one statement" idea (which is what I think you really meant - you can put two statements on one line if you *really* want, but I'm not suggesting that you do) and actually write *three* statements:

  ```
  Tile tile = screen[0][1];
  tile.setColor(Color.RED);
  tile.setStatus(1);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the same of accomplishing this, you could change methods `setColor()` and `setStatus()` to return `this`. Something like:

```
public MyObj setColor(int color) {
    this.color = color;
    return this;
}
```

But I wouldn't do this, it doesn't seem like a good pattern, unless other methods follow the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

Direct possibilities.

- Yes

if setColor method returning  the object of type `screen[0][1]` then you can do

```
screen[0][1].setColor(Color.RED).setStatus(1);
```

- No

if setColor method return type is void. Then only way is

```
screen[0][1].setColor(Color.RED);
screen[0][1].setStatus(1);
```

If you are able to edit the class , there are many other ways we have here so far :)

Answer (score 0):

The possible method can be anyone given by others :

also try it

```
(screen[0][1].setColor(Color.RED)).setStatus(1);
```